# Mantis Integration into Pivotal Tracker

Tags: mantis, pivotaltracker

Guide me how to integrate the Mantis application into the Pivotal Tracker, as of now we bought the license for Pivotal Tracker and from the beginning we are used Mantis application, so now we planned to integrate the Mantis into Pivotal to mapping the defect against the user story

Answer (score 0):

MantisBT comes with a SOAP API enabled, see [MantisBT SOAP API](https://www.mantisbt.org/manual/admin.config.soap.html). This is the main entry point for integrating with MantisBT.

It's also possible to query the database directly, but it's not recommended as the SOAP API properly enforces access controls, isolates you from schema changes and represents the data in a consistent manner.